# C# report programatically passing parameters with reportViewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I've spent a few days attempting to figure this out...

What I have is a list of GUIDs that need to be be passed to a report and then displayed using reportViewer.

I can assemble the comma separated list with the guids no problem... But I'm not sure how to pass the parameters to the report. The composer of the report said all that I need to do is pass a comma separated list of GUIDs

I didn't create the report and do not have direct access to its composition.... (Do i Need Direct access to it?)

```
    private void getreport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //May/20/14 (02:07PM) [AST] - Bootty ton for getting the new RDL report.
    outputBox.Clear();
    reportViewer.Show();

    reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://prdukhscasq01/reportserver");
    //reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    //reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Charge Reconciliation/Combined Charge Report";
    reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "Scheduled Reports/HandOver/UK_HandOver_RoundingReport";



    //May/20/14 (04:14PM) [AST] - Must manually declare the reporting type because Obj+ contains its own report params
    // Dynamically creates a container for the paramerter to be passed to the report.

    int additional_params = 1;
    string patients_guids = "";

        // Counter for keeping track of where we are in the rows to inject the params
    int count = 0 + additional_params;

    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[] yourParams
        = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[dataGridViewPatients.RowCount+additional_params];

        // additional peramiters can be added here.  you must add to the counter for each param in order for thet count to be correnct in the for each loop


        // Grabs current context to allow pulling of data from current session
    //CustomContextObj cc = CustomContextObj.GetInstance();

        //Param #1 logge in user guid


    //** need to create a DB connection using Current connection find this in the CV3ClientVisit table.


    foreach (Patient p in getSelectedPatients().Value)
    {
        patients_guids += p.VisitGUID + "'";
        MessageBox.Show(p.VisitGUID);
    }

 //  yourParams[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("User_Guid",cc.UserGUID.ToString())
               // goes threw all of the names populated to the list
   /* foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewPatients.Rows)
    {
           //keeps our current position in check


        yourParams[count] =
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()+ "," +row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

        ++count;

    }*/



    // EX.. yourParams[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Employe", "data");//Adjust value




        // Completed Refresh
    reportViewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

I'm pretty new to this RDL report stuff and apologize for my ignorance... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have to add: ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(yourParams);

Do you need to pass the list as parameters? I have used RDLC and in it we can directly pass a list as datasource.

Comment: Thanks thats kinda what i figured out there.  There is one parameter that i pass and it throws and exception... which im not catching... not sure why it does that... But its half way working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some searching and finagling i came up with the answer.

Your Parameters must match the names in the report exactly.

GUIDstring is the name of one of the reports parameters.

```
   private void getreport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {



            //May/20/14 (02:07PM) [AST] - Bootty ton for getting the new RDL report.

        outputBox.Clear();

        reportViewer.Show();



        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://prdukhscasq01/reportserver");

        //reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        //reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Charge Reconciliation/Combined Charge Report";

        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Scheduled Reports/HandOver/UK_HandOver_RoundingReport";

        //                                      Scheduled Reports/HandOver/UK_HandOver_RoundingReport





        //May/20/14 (04:14PM) [AST] - Must manually declare the reporting type because Obj+ contains its own report params



        string patients_guids = "";







        foreach (Patient p in getSelectedPatients().Value)

        {

            patients_guids += p.VisitGUID + ",";



        }





        // Assembles the parameter to pass guids.  Matching that of the report.

        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter patient_guids_param =

            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("GUIDstring", patients_guids);



        reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(patient_guids_param);





            // Completed Refresh

        reportViewer.RefreshReport();

    }
```